# mysql update multiple columns with same now()

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to update 2 datetime columns, and I need them to be exactly the same, using mysql version 4.1.20. I'm using this query:

```
mysql> update table set last_update=now(), last_monitor=now() where id=1;
```

It is safe or there is a chance that the columns are update with different time, because of the 2 visible calls to `now()`?
I don't think that it can be update with different values (I think internally mysql calls `now()` just once per row or something similar), but I'm not an expert, what do you think?

**Update:**
Second question was extracted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269245/update-multiple-columns-with-same-value-short-syntax).

Comment: I suggest that you remove your second question from here, and eventually repost it in a separate post.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
mysql> UPDATE table SET last_update=now(), last_monitor=last_update WHERE id=1;
```

I found [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-update.html) in MySQL Docs and after a few tests it works:

> the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2
> have the same value. This behavior differs from standard SQL.
>
> **UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;**

Comment: Is there any way that this wouldn't work? In a procedure or using join with temp tables?

Answer (score 7):

Mysql isn't very clever. When you want to use the same timestamp in multiple update or insert queries, you need to declare a variable.

When you use the `now()` function, the system will call the current timestamp every time you call it in another query.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL evaluates now() once per statement when the statement commences execution.  So it is safe to have multiple visible now() calls per statement.

```
select now(); select now(), sleep(10), now(); select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-11-05 16:54:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| now()               | sleep(10) | now()               |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 2018-11-05 16:54:00 |         0 | 2018-11-05 16:54:00 |
+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (10.00 sec)

+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2018-11-05 16:54:10 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value of a now() in a variable before running the update query and then use that variable to update both the fields `last_update` and `last_monitor`.

This will ensure the now() is executed only once and same value is updated on both columns you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the following code on the default value of the timestamp column:
`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so on update the two columns take the same value.

Comment: AFAIK "on update" has a limit of one column per table, so cannot set it to both columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to be sure that `now()` has the same value you can run two queries (that will answer to your second question too, in that case you are asking to `update last_monitor = to last_update` but `last_update` hasn't been updated yet)

you could do something like:

```
mysql> update table set last_update=now() where id=1;
mysql> update table set last_monitor = last_update where id=1;
```

anyway I think that mysql is clever enough to ask for `now()` only once per query.

Comment: How about the two updates? do you also guess mysql is smart enough to combine them into one statement? because it wont.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to this;

***First***, I would advice you declare now() as a variable before injecting it into the sql statement. Lets say;

```
var x = now();
mysql> UPDATE table SET last_update=$x, last_monitor=$x WHERE id=1;
```

Logically if you want a different input for last_monitor then you will add another variable like;

```
var y = time();
mysql> UPDATE table SET last_update=$x, last_monitor=$y WHERE id=1;
```

This way you can use the variables as many times as you can, not only in mysql statements but also in the server-side scripting-language(like PHP) you are using in your project.
Remember these same variables can be inserted as inputs in a form on the front-end of the application. That makes the project dynamic and not static.

***Secondly*** if now() indicates time of update then using mysql you can decalre the property of the row as a timestamp. Every time a row is inserted or updated time is updated too.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though this is a solution to the problem, it doesn't really answer the question which is "Is there a problem using the mysql built-in NOW() function?". Also you suggest using an external language which the poster may have no control over. Your 2nd suggestion I am unsure of (my recollection of mysql isn't that detailed) but supporting it with links to some docs/examples would give far more credibility.

Comment: In my 2nd suggestion, if now() is to be used as a timestamp whenever any update takes place, the following link can help out;   https://alvinalexander.com/mysql/mysql-update-timestamp-on-update-sql-update-query        In my 1st suggestion, each column in a mysql table is independent. Hence data input(like using one variable in the question above) is done independently. However you can compare and contrast data in different columns using operators like >,<,=,!=,!<. This simply means you cant input data into the cols like this;  mysql> update table set last_update=last_monitor=now() where id=1;