# Update multiple columns with same value, short syntax

Tags: mysql

Question extracted from [mysql update multiple columns with same now()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802256/mysql-update-multiple-columns-with-same-now)

> Second question why this query doesn't update the columns:
>
> ```
> mysql> update table set last_update=last_monitor=now() where id=1;
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

Created a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/036d0b/1) to illustrate the confusion.

```
create table t1 (
  c1 INT NOT NULL,
  c2 INT NOT NULL
);
insert into t1 values (0,0);

update t1 set c1=c2=1;

select * from t1;
| c1 | c2 |
|----|----|
|  0 |  0 |
```

I am expecting `c1` and `c2` to be set to `1` or the query to fail due to syntax error.

Actual result is that the query is succeeding without updating the columns, so `c1` or `c2` remain at initial value of `0`

As the current behavior does not makes sense to me, I'm definitely missing something. Can someone share some light on how this expression gets evaluated by MySQL engine (or any other SQL engine) ?

Comment: Why don't you set the default value to one for those columns?

Comment: But c2 equals 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am expecting c1 and c2 to be set to 1 or the query to fail due to
>   syntax error.

Neither is true.
The expression:

```
c1=c2=1
```

is evaluated like:

```
c1=(c2=1)
```

For MySql the boolean expression `c2=1` evaluates to `0` or `1` for `false` or `true` respectively.
So `0` or `1` will be assigned to `c1` and in this case since `c2=1` is `false` the result will be `0`.
You must use separate assignments to each column:

```
update t1 
set 
  c1=1,
  c2=1;
```

Comment: One can always do `update t1 set c1=1, c2=c1;` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802797/207603). Glad you gave the inside on how the expression is evaluated as that was exactly what I was looking for, even do I now realized did not explicitly asked for it (update the question now).

Answer (score 0):

Execute this:

```
  SELECT c2=1 FROM t1
```

Now grab a cup of coffee and have a good think.